# Simplifying Ideals to principal ideals

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, finite-fields

I am given that $(6,2\sqrt{6}, 3\sqrt{6},6)$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ and I am trying to show that it is equal to $(\sqrt{6})$ (without the use of norms). Since there is closure under addition in the ideal $3\sqrt{6}-2\sqrt{6}\implies \sqrt{6}$ is in the ideal. I can also see trivially that I can generate everything in $(6,2\sqrt{6},3\sqrt{6},6)$
from $\sqrt{6}\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ but I am not sure how this implies equality.

Comment: With $\,w=\sqrt 6\,$ we have $\,I = w(w,2,3,w) = w(1)=(w)\,$ by $\,3-2=1\,$ is in the 2nd factor.  Best to delete this question once you're sure you've grokked it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the ideal $I$. As you showed, $\sqrt{6} \in I$, which implies $(\sqrt{6}) \subset I$. But you also said that all the generators of $I$ are in $(\sqrt{6})$, which means $I \subset (\sqrt{6})$. Put those together and you have equality.

Comment: For the last implication is this the same as saying since $(6),(2\sqrt{6}),(3\sqrt{6}) \subset (\sqrt{6})$ then $(6)+(2\sqrt{6})+(3\sqrt{6})+(6)=(6, 2\sqrt{6},3\sqrt{6},6)\subset(\sqrt{6})$? Since Ideals are closed under addition.

Comment: Sure, that's equivalent. Personally, I read the notation $(a, b)$ as "the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$," or "the smallest ideal containing both $a$ and $b$," rather than as $(a) + (b)$, but both are valid definitions.